# Covert enum to dropdown list in core2.1 razor pages

Tags: c#, enums, dropdown, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

i have the following enum

```
public class Blog {

   public enum BlogType {
     Article,
     News
   }

}
```

i want to convert it to drop down list, but i get error :
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'Blog.BlogType' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable**

my code :

```
IList<SelectListItem> list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Blog.BlogType))
.Cast<Blog.BlogType>()
.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() })
.ToList();

SelectList data = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
```

i tried several solutions but i got the same issue..

thanks ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using enum for dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740638/using-enum-for-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-mvc-core)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `Html.GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>` method in a select tag helper:

```
<select asp-for="BlogType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BlogType>()">
    <option value="">Pick one</option>
</select>
```

See more about using the select tag helper and enumerations in Razor Pages here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/select-tag-helper#enumerations

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.EnumProperty, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Blog)).Cast<Blog>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }))
```